# how to refresh datatable in JSf with session bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Session Managed Bean where I have a list that I show in datatable and when I click in button I change the list in the managed bean but the table didnt change in the JSF page :

```
<p:commandButton id="someId" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2()}">
    <f:ajax  render="koka"/>
</p:commandButton> 

<p:dataTable id="koka" var="op" value="#{gestionduplanning.listop}" style="width: 700px;float: left;">
    <p:column headerText ="operateur" style="width:50px;" >       
        <h:outputText value="#{op.operateur.matricule}"/>
    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

How can I update the table in JSF and I need to keep my managed bean as session bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `<f:ajax  render="koka"/>` and add `update="koka"` to your `<p:commandButton`

```
<p:commandButton update="koka" id="someId" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2()}"/>
```

---

Also you better don't nest `f:ajax` with inside Primefaces components and vice versa...

`f:ajax` is meant to use with native JSF components

`p:ajax` is meant to use with PrimeFaces components

It is fine to have both , Primefaces components and JSF native components in one page, just make sure to use `p:ajax` in Primefaces components and `f:ajax` in JSF native components

Comment: i face problem when i update my JSF page because i have jquery sortable when i use update the drag and drop didnt work after any solution ?

Comment: post a new question with a proper title and description and I will post an answer...

Answer (score 2):

First thing, you are using PrimeFaces, `p:commandButton` are already AJAX so you don't need `f:ajax` :

```
<p:commandButton id="someId" value="Button" action="#{gestionduplanning.exec2()}" update="koka" />
```

Other thing, make sure your data source (`getListop()`) is updated in the bean by `exec2()`.

Comment: Well it depends on how it is programmed, is it always loading from database, or returning a variable in the bean that is initialized with @PostConstruct or...

Comment: Im doing it with PostConstruct on a method called init(). Inside that method, I am calling the DAO method that retrieves all rows from the database

Comment: So you can call `init()` again inside your action method! (or only the required part if you have other things you don't want to execute)

Comment: Excellent. That is what I needed. Sorry for my ignorant question. I guess I am starting to learn now

Answer (score 0):

Refresh primefaces datatable using Java when clicking on the button.

DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("formId:dataTableId");
dataTable.reset();
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("formId:dataTableId");